# scaling x values of a graph based on a specific function

Tags: plotting, ticks

I have the following equation in which the variable Q is raised to 1.85.

```
f(Q)= A*Q^1.85
```

A is known constant. For practical reasons I want to plot the above equation as this

```
f(X)=A*X where X=Q^1.85
```

That would be very easy but I want to have the x axis displaying the Q values not the Q^1.85 (or X). From what I could find myself, the solution could be using the 'func' as one of the options of 'Ticks', at least this is what I read [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ticks.html). But no matter how I much I searched, I couldn't find an example of properly introducing a function to plot the Q values instead of Q^1.85.

How could this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
A=1
f[Q_]:= A Q^1.85    

Plot[
f[Q],
{Q,0,10},
ScalingFunctions->{{#^1.85&,#^(1/1.85)&},"Linear"},  
Ticks-> {Range[0,10,1],Automatic},
AxesLabel->{"Q","f[Q]"}]
```

[image]